# one-way ANOVA to compare means for variables that are correlated: multicollinearity

Tags: anova, multicollinearity

I'm looking at some reviewer comments regarding a manuscript that looks at 23 chemicals in lizard blood from three sites. Many of these elements, as expected, correlate with each other to correlate with each other; multicollinearity.
The authors performed 23x one-way ANOVAs to compare the means of each element at each of the three sites to show that lizards at site1 had significantly elevated levels of arsenic relative to and adjacent site (site2) as well as their control (site3). They followed up with a PCA and found a decent separation of the sites along PC1 thanks to arsenic and a few other elements.

The reviewers argued that the one-way ANOVA was inappropriate given the multicollinearity. Since there is no dependant and independent variables, why is this an issue? Is it something to do with inflated variance estimates used by ANOVA? Everything I find for multicollinearity issues appears to be about regressions.

If there is significant multicollinearity between some of the 23 elements, then which method can be used for simple means testing? Should the authors simply rely on relative differences between mean element concentrations?